# javascript in html not working form validation

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried everything and the form validation javascript still is not working inside my html document.  Can anyone one tell me what is wrong here because i can not find it.

Here is the javascript and html code shown below to show that i am doing it correctly but it still is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function validateForm() {

    var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
    var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
    var bio = document.getElementById("bio").value



    if (fname == null || fname == ""){
        alert("Firstname not filled out.");
        return false;
    }

    if (lname == null || lname == ""){
        alert("Lastname not filled out");
        return false;

    }

    if (month == null || month == ""){
        alert("Birthday not filled out");
        return false;
    }

    if (day == null || day == ""){
        alert("Birthday not filled out");
        return false;
    }

    if (year == null || year == ""){
        alert("Birthday not filled out");
        return false;
    }

    if (bio == null || bio == ""){
        alert("About me not filled out");
        return false;
    }

}


</script>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="userinfo" name="update" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">First Name:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname"></input>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Last Name:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname"></input>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Email:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Sex:</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Male</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Female</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Status:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <select class="form-control" name="stat">
                            <option></option>
                            <option>Single</option>
                            <option>In a relationship</option>
                            <option>Married</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Birthday:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <select class="form-control" name="month">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>January</option>
                    <option>Febuary</option>
                    <option>March</option>
                    <option>April</option>
                    <option>May</option>
                    <option>June</option>
                    <option>July</option>
                    <option>August</option>
                    <option>September</option>
                    <option>October</option>
                    <option>November</option>
                    <option>December</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                <select class="form-control" name="day">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>11</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                    <option>13</option>
                    <option>14</option>
                    <option>15</option>
                    <option>16</option>
                    <option>17</option>
                    <option>18</option>
                    <option>19</option>
                    <option>20</option>
                    <option>21</option>
                    <option>22</option>
                    <option>23</option>
                    <option>24</option>
                    <option>25</option>
                    <option>26</option>
                    <option>27</option>
                    <option>28</option>
                    <option>29</option>
                    <option>30</option>
                    <option>31</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                <select class="form-control" name="year">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>2015</option>
                    <option>2014</option>
                    <option>2013</option>
                    <option>2012</option>
                    <option>2011</option>
                    <option>2010</option>
                    <option>2009</option>
                    <option>2008</option>
                    <option>2007</option>
                    <option>2006</option>
                    <option>2005</option>
                    <option>2004</option>
                    <option>2003</option>
                    <option>2002</option>
                    <option>2001</option>
                    <option>2000</option>
                    <option>1999</option>
                    <option>1998</option>
                    <option>1997</option>
                    <option>1996</option>
                    <option>1995</option>
                    <option>1994</option>
                    <option>1993</option>
                    <option>1992</option>
                    <option>1991</option>
                    <option>1990</option>
                    <option>1989</option>
                    <option>1988</option>
                    <option>1987</option>
                    <option>1986</option>
                    <option>1985</option>
                    <option>1984</option>
                    <option>1983</option>
                    <option>1982</option>
                    <option>1981</option>
                    <option>1980</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">About Me:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="bio" id="bio"></textarea><br>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
```

Comment: Is this really the smallest repro you can do to demonstrate the problem? Reduce it to only include one field and one validation if that also causes problems, because then it is much simpler to check your code.

Comment: I decided to show the who thing for some reason, but what could cause the javascript to not work?

Comment: the problem is more of the submit button you need to add the id to the <select> because in your scripts you recovered the values of <select> with getElementById

Answer (score 2):

hi your script is very good, but your html should be something like this [worked demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Imx7IBDWvSS8SCIl3Ch?p=preview): more of the submit button you need to add the id to the `<select>` because in your scripts you recovered the values of `<select>` with getElementById

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="userinfo" name="update" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname"/>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Sex:</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Male</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Female</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Status:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <select class="form-control" id="stat" name="stat">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>Single</option>
                        <option>In a relationship</option>
                        <option>Married</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Birthday:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
            <select class="form-control" id="month" name="month">
                <option></option>
                <option>January</option>
                <option>Febuary</option>
                <option>March</option>
                <option>April</option>
                <option>May</option>
                <option>June</option>
                <option>July</option>
                <option>August</option>
                <option>September</option>
                <option>October</option>
                <option>November</option>
                <option>December</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
            <select class="form-control" id="day" name="day">
                <option></option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
                <option>9</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>11</option>
                <option>12</option>
                <option>13</option>
                <option>14</option>
                <option>15</option>
                <option>16</option>
                <option>17</option>
                <option>18</option>
                <option>19</option>
                <option>20</option>
                <option>21</option>
                <option>22</option>
                <option>23</option>
                <option>24</option>
                <option>25</option>
                <option>26</option>
                <option>27</option>
                <option>28</option>
                <option>29</option>
                <option>30</option>
                <option>31</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
            <select class="form-control" id="year" name="year">
                <option></option>
                <option>2015</option>
                <option>2014</option>
                <option>2013</option>
                <option>2012</option>
                <option>2011</option>
                <option>2010</option>
                <option>2009</option>
                <option>2008</option>
                <option>2007</option>
                <option>2006</option>
                <option>2005</option>
                <option>2004</option>
                <option>2003</option>
                <option>2002</option>
                <option>2001</option>
                <option>2000</option>
                <option>1999</option>
                <option>1998</option>
                <option>1997</option>
                <option>1996</option>
                <option>1995</option>
                <option>1994</option>
                <option>1993</option>
                <option>1992</option>
                <option>1991</option>
                <option>1990</option>
                <option>1989</option>
                <option>1988</option>
                <option>1987</option>
                <option>1986</option>
                <option>1985</option>
                <option>1984</option>
                <option>1983</option>
                <option>1982</option>
                <option>1981</option>
                <option>1980</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">About Me:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="bio" id="bio"></textarea><br>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"></div>
             <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"><input type="submit"/></div>
        </form>
```

Comment: I would add this info to the beginning of your answer

Comment: thanks but i already had the submit button at the end i just accidentally didn't show it on here

Comment: the problem is more  of the submit button you need to add the id to the <select> because in your scripts you recovered the values of <select> with  getElementById

Answer (score 1):

All your html select set the wrong property 
Try:

```
<select class="form-control" name="month">

set to :

<select class="form-control" id="month">
```

Comment: I have both name= and id on there

Comment: I didn't see it in your code(select component), if you call getElementById() you must set a  id  property. @aitnasser has marked for you